# Upgrading to ASP.NET 4.7.1 for connection string dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, webforms

I upgraded a WebForms application from 2.0 to 4.0 previously (no underlying changes, same application internally) and have now updated it to 4.7.1 as I want to make the libraries .NET Standard 2.0 ones so that I can, hopefully, leverage them in an updated application.

So I did the same thing as before, but I'm trying to understand how to implement the dependency injection part such that those libraries are usable (specifically, connection strings being handled in the host application for the libraries).

From what I was looking at, it talks about implementing configuration, but there isn't a Program.cs + Startup.cs file here. I attempted to start by adding a Program.cs (and try to figure out how the application would then know to look for it), but everything I see seems ASP.NET Core tailored.

My question is: how do I implement DI so that the .NET Standard 2.0 libraries for data access/logic are leveraged appropriately and how would this be leveraged in aspx code behinds (although, if it could just be done by making the libraries themselves do most of that, that would be great too)?

Comment: You are conflating versions of the .NET Framework and BCL with versions of ASP.NET. The latter are web application frameworks built on the former.

Comment: I would suggest not trying to jury-rig a WebForms application to use DI unless you really know what you're doing. It's like trying to convert a 1971 Plymouth Cricket to electric. Sure you could, if you have lots of time and energy, but why?

Comment: @AluanHaddad maybe I should've explicitly stated Framework 4.7.1, but that was the intent there. Technically the applications would still live fine in Framework 2.0, but because I'm trying to bring in the DI leveraged by Core, needed to upgrade to 4.7.1.

Comment: Please reread my comment.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's fair. The reason why being is that if I can get all/majority of the logic into the Standard libraries, it'd likely be an easier sell to migrate off WebForms to Razor Pages (and a switch to Core).

Comment: What works for me is usage of the StructureMap IoC/DI container.I've been using it in all my ASP.NET Web Forms projects. https://structuremap.github.io/